# C# SSH.NET CreateCommand/RunCommand does not work

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, ssh.net

I would like to create an application to send SSH commands to HP Switches and some other devices. But from HP Switch I get response *"SSH command execution is not supported."*.

I use this part of a code.

```
SshClient sshclient = new SshClient(IP,username, pass);
sshclient.Connect();
SshCommand sc = sshclient.CreateCommand("conf");
sc.Execute();
string answer = sc.Result;
label9.Text = answer;
```

Any ideas how to make the interactive shell emulation?
I found only this thread regarding to this issue.
[phpseclib - attempting to connect to an HP procurve switch returns error: SSH command execution is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115252/phpseclib-attempting-to-connect-to-an-hp-procurve-switch-returns-error-ssh-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct in general. But it seems, that the particular device does not support the SSH "exec" channel, what is behind the `SshCommand` class.

As the [answer to the question you have linked yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12115252/850848#13436163) suggests, you have to unfortunately emulate a shell by using SSH "shell" channel.

For that use `SshClient.CreateShell` and write the command to its input stream.

Note that this is just a workaround for your specific situation. In general, the "shell" channel shall not be used for automation.